# If I strip out INSERT, DELETE, DROP, etc., can someone still do damage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

If I have a open form where someone can enter any sql statement to my sql server for internal testing, and I strip out the following keywords from the statement before executing it, is it still dangerous for someone to perform mutations?

```
INSERT, DELETE, DROP, UPDATE, CREATE, ALTER, TRUNCATE, EXEC
```

The sql account that will run these operations has read/write permissions.

Comment: sure... `SELECT ...lots of nasty php code here... INTO OUTFILE /your/document/root/hackme.php` and poof, your server is pwned, your dog has boot marks, and your mom runs off to join a cult. To be brutally honest, the fact that you're asking this question at all basically proves you're not able to produce such a site in a secure manner. I know I'm not able to. I wouldn't even want to try.

Comment: Just stop trying to outsmart the hackers by stripping and "cleansing" your user inputs... you'll always miss something.... Just always use **parametrized queries** and all your SQL injection vows are gone ...

Comment: The answer is to simply not `have a open form where someone can enter any sql statement` - do you hand them the keys to your car too? Stop doing that. Period.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didn't do it, its just the environment that I'm in!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - SELECT INTO can be used, maybe others.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

It is better to use the permissions available for users accounts properly. Create an account with read-only privileges, all mainstream servers will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the permissions then could you wrap the select statement into a `CREATE VIEW AS` then run the view? This should (depending on your environment) error if anything other than select is run.

Answer (score 0):

If an attacker has just read-only privilege against a single table, and they can trick your app into executing arbitrary SQL, they can perpetrate at least a denial of service attack by running a cartesian product:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table, table, table, table, table, table, table, table, table, table
ORDER BY RAND();
```

If table has 100 rows, can your sql server handle sorting 100<sup>10</sup> rows without crashing?  :-)

The conclusion is that limiting SQL privileges can be part of the solution, but it's not a full solution to protect yourself from attackers.  You need to know how to use multiple techniques, and code defensively.

I cover different defense techniques and which ones are useful in different circumstances in my presentation:
[SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies)